# MySQL select char(0x542d01 using ?) smile issue

Tags: mysql, sql

From the command

```
select char(0x542d01);
```

I expect

```
T-1
```

But MySQL returns

```
T-:)
```

From a little of google research I found the result can be modified by specifying the charset in the command, something like

```
select char(0x542d01 using utf8);
```

But I wasn't able to find a way to read `T-1` from `0x542d01`. Would some one give me a hand here, please?

More generally, I think I have a charset issue here.

Comment: Why do you expect character U+01 to render as `1`? The character code for `1` is U+31.

Comment: Someone else said "I've inserted this (`0x542d01`) and I want to see this (`T-1`)". Should I talk with Mrs Someone else or is there something I could do before? I would appreciate to have a little description about the meaning of `U+01`.

Answer (score 0):

Function `convert` can be used to convert data between different charsets.

### Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html

Here is an example of your data:

```
mysql> select convert(0x542d01 using utf8);
+------------------------------+
| convert(0x542d01 using utf8) |
+------------------------------+
| T-                          |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In your answer I'm missing exactly what I've tried ask for, the right most character. There are three bytes (`0x54`, `0x2d` and `0x01`). In your answer, using convert seems to throw away the last one (`0x01`). Why?

Comment: Would you mind pointing out which charset should I try, in order to translate `0x01` to `1`?

Comment: Do exist a charset in which `0x01` translates to `1`?